# Изображение меняется, но не на, что указано в пути, приложение WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

возникла проблема при создании приложения. Мне необходимо при нажатии на кнопку менять изображение, однако вместо смены на указанное в коде, оно меняется на ничего. Были предположения, что проблема в путях, однако не получилось разобраться. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

(Изображения хранятся в папке проекта)

```
  
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private int currentImageIndex = 0;
        private string[] imagePaths = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png" };


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePaths[currentImageIndex], UriKind.Relative));
            image.Source = bitmapImage;
            currentImageIndex++;
            if (currentImageIndex >= imagePaths.Length)
            {
                currentImageIndex = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `new Uri(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, imagePaths[currentImageIndex]))`. Чтобы узнать, почему не работает, выведите `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, она не обязательно должна быть той, которую ожидаете.

Comment: ```new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, imagePaths[currentImageIndex]));``` для приложения Wpf в .NET Core будет работать следующий код.

Comment: @aepot ```Application.StartupPath``` из пространства имен System.Windows.Forms, то есть если проекте Wpf от StartupPath не будет толку

Comment: @xellan да, вы правы, это я перепутал.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за помощь, проблему решить удалось)